# How to call all members of a picture box array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, picturebox

I'm making space invaders, and I'm using arrays for the first time, I have yet to learn them in class so I'm kind of free-balling it.

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)                 Handles FireTimer.Tick
    Fire.Top = Fire.Top - 7
    For index = 0 To 26
         If Me.Fire.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbxMyEnemies(index).Bounds) Then
            pbxMyEnemies(index).Visible = False
            pbxMyEnemies(index).Enabled = False
            pbxMyEnemies(index).Left = 732
            pbxMyEnemies(index).Top = 55
            FireTimer.Enabled = False
            Fire.Visible = False
            z = 0
        ElseIf Me.Fire.Bounds.IntersectsWith(stopper.Bounds) Then
            z = 0
        End If



    Next
    If pbxMyEnemies().Visible = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("gotem")
    End If

End Sub
```

Where 'If pbxMyEnemies().visible = false then
   Messagebox.Show("gottem")
end if

is where I want it to check if all of the picture boxes in the array are visible false. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FireTimer.Tick
  Dim Test As Boolean = True
  Fire.Top = Fire.Top - 7
  For index = 0 To 26
    If Me.Fire.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbxMyEnemies(index).Bounds) Then
      pbxMyEnemies(index).Visible = False
      pbxMyEnemies(index).Enabled = False
      pbxMyEnemies(index).Left = 732
      pbxMyEnemies(index).Top = 55
      FireTimer.Enabled = False
      Fire.Visible = False
      z = 0
    ElseIf Me.Fire.Bounds.IntersectsWith(stopper.Bounds) Then
      z = 0
      Test = False
    End If
  Next
  If Test Then
    MessageBox.Show("gotem")
  End If
End Sub
```